# Node.js: Multiple very heavy requests at the same time, single response to all requests

Tags: node.js, caching, concurrency

I am sorry that I can't come up with a better title.

I always have this problem (when coding in node.js also python) but I think my solution is kind dirty.

I am here to seek a better solution for this problem.

Here is the scenario:

> Your server is doing a very very heavy task upon a special http request (like generating browser screenshot for an URL/generating game server banner with statistics). Whoever did a HTTP request to your server will get the same response. The response will be cached for a long time.
>
> For example, in the browser screenshot generating HTTP request, your server is expected to spawn a phantomjs, capture the screenshot, save it and cache it for a long time, then respond with the PNG captured. The HTTP request after this should hit the cache.

The pseudo code to scenario:

```
server.get(":urlname.png", function(req, res, next) {
    var cached = cache.get(req.params_urlname);
    if (cached) {
        res.send(cached);
        return;
    }
    // This will take very long time
    generateScreenshot(req.params_urlname, function(pngData) {
        cache.set(req.params_urlname, pngData, LONG_TIME);
        res.send(cached);
    });
});
```

Here is the problem:

> Imagine that you have a screenshot generating URL
>   (http://yourserver.com/generate-screenshot/google.png). The screenshot
>   is not generated nor cached yet.
>
> Your posted the URL in a very popular forum, and there are 1000 HTTP requests to the that URL at the same time! It means that your server will have to spawn 1000 phantomjs and all of them together will generate screenshot of google.com at the same time, which is crazy!
>
> In other words, the heavy function should be executed only once for generating cache.

My current code solution to the problem:

```
var pendingResponse = {};
server.get(":urlname.png", function(req, res, next) {
    var cached = cache.get(req.params_urlname);
    if (cached) {
        res.send(cached);
        return;
    }
    // The screenshot is currently generating for other request. Let's mark this response as pending.
    if (req.params_urlname in pendingResponse) {
        pendingResponse[req.params_urlname].push(res);
        return;
    }
    // The screenshot needs to be generated now. Let's mark the future response as pending.
    req.params_urlname[req.params_urlname] = [];

    // This will take very long time
    generateScreenshot(req.params_urlname, function(pngData) {

        cache.set(req.params_urlname, pngData, LONG_TIME);
        res.send(cached);

        // Let's respond all the pending responses with the PNG data as well.
        for (var i in pendingResponse[req.params_urlname]) {
            var pRes = pendingResponse[req.params_urlname][i];
            pRes.send(cached);
        }

        // No longer mark the future responses as pending.
        delete pendingResponse[req.params_urlname];
    });
});
```

This solution works. However, I consider this solution dirty, because it not reusable at all. Also, I think it may cause resource leak. Is there any better solution / library?

Comment: I'm not too good at javascript, but isn't it true that if your 'generate_screenshot' is synchronous then the callbacks of server.get(...) will run one-by-one and so your first approach is fine? I also suspect that you would prefer to have it asynchronous, and that maybe in that case the "memoize" module could be of interest to you in order to achieve what you want (https://github.com/medikoo/memoize).

Comment: @starikoff Yes, generate_screenshot should be asynchronous. My fault here. How does memoize module allows only 1 generate_screenshot() function executing at the same time?

Comment: I can't read javascript of this complexity. From what I could discern ('ext/async.js') and from what I would expect (I had implemented a similar thing manually in the past in Java for a GWT project), my wild **guess** is the following:

Comment: The module has a global cache for "running" computations. A computation is a "callback" object that can collect other callbacks and, when called, run them all and wipe itself from the cache. By applying "memoize" to an async function _f_ a new async function with the same signature is created. When called, it:
1) tries to get a computation for this function+parameters, from the cache,
2) if there's none, creates it and adds to the cache,
3) in any case adds the callback to the computation,
4) if it created a new computation, runs the original function _f_ with this computation as a callback.

Comment: Your cache can contain either the image or a promise.  So, the first request to create the image puts a promise in the cache.  Subsequent requests that come in right away will check the cache and find the promise and they will just attach `.then()` handlers to that promise.  When the first request finishes making the image, it resolves the promise and then replaces the promise in the cache with the actual image data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proof-of-concept server doing this result caching using a [memoizee](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memoizee) package (not only removes the necessity to cache computations in progress, but also allows to remove the "cache" altogether):

```
var express = require('express');
var memoize = require('memoizee');

function longComputation(urlName, cb) {
  console.log('called for ' + urlName);
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('done for ' + urlName);
    cb();
  }, 5000);
}

var memoizedLongComputation = memoize(longComputation, {async: true, maxAge: 20000});

var app = express();
app.get('/hang/:urlname', function (req, res, next) {
  memoizedLongComputation(req.params.urlname, function () {
    res.send('hang over');
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Here we make the result be cached for 20 seconds.

When I start the server and then run in the shell

```
for i in `seq 1 10`; do curl http://localhost:3000/hang/url1; done
```

(or just open several browser tabs and quickly navigate them all to http://localhost:3000/hang/url1), I see one `"called for url1"` and in 5 s one `"done for url1"` message in the console, meaning only one "real" `longComputation` call was made. If I repeat it shortly after (less than in 20 s), there are no additional messages, and results are returned instantaneously, because they are cached. If I repeat the command later (in more than 20 s), there's again one call only.